# Repetitive pattern of relationships in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Suppose I have nodes that can be joined by a set of pattern of paths, for example:

```
(x:Class {code:'xxx'})<-[:a]-()-[:b]->()<-[:a]-()-[:b]->()<-[:a]-()-[:b]->()<-[:a]-()-[:b]->(y:Class{code:'yyy'})
```

There can be a variable number of `<-[:a]-()-[:b]->` between `x` and `y`. How can I get the shortest path if it exist between `x` and `y` ?

Comment: Have you looked at [`shortestPath()`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/match/#query-shortest-path)?

Comment: Shortest can be used, but at the same time, i want to be able to define a pattern that I can see in this path

Comment: Does each `a` relationship have the same type and parameters? ... or just same type?  Same question for `b` relationship.

Comment: `a` and `b` always are the same type since they repeat, but have different parameters

Comment: And when you "define a pattern", does that include the specific types for relationship `a` and `b`? ... or `a` could be any type, etc.?

Comment: No, it's a specific type

Comment: Perhaps [`relationshipFilter`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_sequences) from the APOC procedures will be useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the path expander procs from APOC Procedures provide a way to handle repeating sequences.

However it looks like you're not just looking for a specific end node, but for one that occurs at that point in the sequence (and not, say, as the node in the middle of those relationship pairs).

In that case we need to include the labelFilter too, to specific which node in the sequence we're interested in. Or we can just use the `sequence` config parameter instead of both the label and relationship filters.

```
MATCH (start:Class {code:'xxx'}), (end:Class{code:'yyy'})
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(start, {endNodes:[end], sequence:'>Class, <a, *, b>', limit:1}) YIELD path
RETURN path
```

We supply the end nodes we're interested in (since we already know those, we matched to them already), then we supply the sequence of alternating node labels and relationship types (using `*` as a standin for a node of any label, and using a prefix of `>` as an end node filter, meaning we want paths that end at this :Class node in this position of the sequence).

The path expander procs use breadth-first expansion, and the `limit:1` means the first path we encounter to a node that is both an end node, and that satisfies the sequence pattern (a :Class node at that point in the repeating sequence) will be our shortest path.

Comment: The first encountered path isn't necessarily the only shortest path, yes?

Comment: Correct, there could be others of the same length. At the moment the proc doesn't find all the others, you'd have to extract the `length(path)` then call the proc again passing that length as the `maxLevel` config property, and without the limit.